# Express this logarithm in terms of a and b

Tags: logarithms

How do I express **$\log_52$** in terms of $a$ and $b$ if:

$\log_62 =a$ and
$\log_53 =b$

I've tried:

- Converting the $a$ and $b$ equations to fractions, and substituting $\log2$ and $\log5$ with $a\log6$ and $(\log3)/b$ respectively, but I ended up with the same equation after simplifying things out.
- I've also tried to convert the $2$ in $\log_52$ into fractions and go from there, but I went up going in circles and never got anywhere.

How would I solve this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using change of base (change to base 5):

$$ \log_6 2 = \frac{\log_5 2}{\log_5 6} = \frac{\log_5 2}{\log_5 3 + \log_5 2}$$

$$ a = \frac{\log_5 2}{b + \log_5 2}$$

$$ ab = (1-a)\log_5 2$$

$$ \log_5 2 = ?$$

I trust you can finish the rest

Answer (score 0):

$a=\log_62=\dfrac{\log2}{\log2+\log3}$ as $\log(ab)=\log a+\log b$  when all the logarithms are defined.

Now express $\log2$ in terms of $\log3$

Again, $b=\log_53=\dfrac{\log3}{\log5}\iff\log5=\dfrac{\log3}b$

Now $\log_52=\dfrac{\log2}{\log5}=?$

---

Alternatively,

$$\log_53=b\implies3=5^b$$

$$\log_62=a\implies2=6^a=(5^b)^a2^a\iff2^{1-a}=5^{ab}$$

Take log wrt base $5$  $$(1-a)\log_52=ab$$

Comment: $a(\log2 + \log3)=\log2$?


so $a\log2+a\log3=\log2$,


$a\log2-\log2=a\log3$,


$a=-a\log3$


Is this correct?

Comment: At line 3, it should be $b=\log_53=\frac{\log3}{\log5}$

Comment: @MarcelYuwono, $$a\log3=(1-a)\log2\iff\log3=\dfrac{1-a}a\log2$$

Comment: @Nicholas, Rectified & added another approach